# Pass javascript mouse events through webview (iframe) to another webview (iframe) underneath

Tags: javascript, html, css, webview, electron

I'm making an electron app that loads several web pages into one page.  Think of this like a splash screen that shows several different widgets in one place.  The user can choose which screens they want to add, a calculator, messaging app, etc.  Currently, I load each one of these "widgets" into it's own separate webview (similar to an iFrame), and stack each one of these webviews on top of each other.  The main reason I'm doing this, is I don't want the code for each "widget" to be able to see any other code for any other page (AKA, a "widget").  Each webview has an absolute position of 0,0, and a width/height of 100%, and a transparent background.  This allows the developers of these widgets full access to the screen, or just part of the screen, if they wish.

It is here that I run into my issue.  Say that I have my first "widget", a calculator, loaded in a webview.  Underneath this webview, I have another "widget" loaded in a sepearte webview, a messaging app.  The problem is the first "widget", even if it's webview contents are only using 10% of the screen, is in a webview frame that is taking up the 100% of the screen.  When the user tries to click on the messaging webview, which is loaded underneath the first calculator webview, their mouse event is caught by the topmost webview and blocked from propagating down.  [I feel like a picture may better explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXQxI.png).  This picture may seem a little confusing, but what I'm trying to display that webview #1 (the blue box), is overlapping webview #2 (the red box).  While I can click the calculator widget just fine, I cannot click through to the messaging widget **as webview #1 is catching the event**.

So here lies my problem.  I need my mouse events to pass through webview #1 to webview #2 (and then #3... #4.... #5.... etc) if it does not land on any element in said webview.

Here are a few things that I've tried:

**Attempt 1**
Applying the `pointer-events` CSS attribute on the webviews to `none`, then setting the `body`'s `pointer-events` of the HTML loaded into each webview to `auto`.  However the mouse event just pass completely through each webview then.

**Attempt 2**
Instead of using webviews, I actually just load transparent electron windows on top of eachother and load each widget in them.  Unfortunately transparent windows still block mouse events in empty areas.

**Attempt 3**
Loading a little javascript into each webview that sets an event handler on the page's body.  If a mouse cursor fires and hits the page's background (without hitting an element), it sends a message back to the host page who then sends it down to the next webview underneath, and the process repeats.  I've run into several problems with this, the most major one being sending the event object from one webview to the host page and then back into another webview from there.  I believe I'm running into security precautions that prevent event objects from being sent via IPC.  It also feels like an extreme workaround.

What I'm starting to fear is that this is literally impossible.  **Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?**  I'm open to ideas on how else I can achieve the desired result.  (As long as each webpage cannot see the other web pages, and I can [strip out node-integration](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-disable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content), I'm happy)

Comment: Can you add a code example? Perhaps you can create a CodePen that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: If the widgets themselves are smaller, then why have the webviews cover the whole screen to begin with? You must have some mechanism to position the widgets within the respective webview - so why not apply that to the webviews instead, position them at the place where the actual widget is supposed to show, and limit their width & height to that of the widget as well …?

Comment: @misorude The problem lies with the fact that I have no clue with what each widget will look like.  They could contain one small popup window, or could consist of 3 separate windows.  I suppose I could add a way for one to specify the x, y, height, and width of each widget, but I would like to avoid restricting widgets in that way.